# Converting phone wall mount to ethernet mount

Tags: ethernet, telephone

I currently have a telephone wall mount. 1 near the router, 2 more in another 2 rooms.

When I remove the wall mount, I can see 4 wires from the cable.
Red, Blue, White and Grey.

My question is, can this cable be converted to ethernet so that I can connect my pc in another room using ethernet straight to the router?

I attached some photos.
[Room](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m75V6.jpg)
[Near Router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qm13g.jpg)

Comment: Better ask home user questions on SuperUser.

Answer (score 2):

No, a phone cable is not suitable for ethernet, even if it could work short distances, 4 wires would limit you to max 100mbit.

Instead use the existing cable to pull a new ethernet cable.